# Does a function definition need to be inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there anything wrong with using useEffect in this way?  A lot of examples that I have seen seem to put the function definition inside useEffect as well. However, I want to be able to call the function again after an item is deleted/updated.

```
      const getSchools = async () => {
           const data = await getDocs(schoolsCollectionRef)
           setSchools(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id})))
           console.log(data.docs)
      
       }

    useEffect(() =>{
             getSchools()
    }, [])
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this.

Comment: 'ref' is suspicious, and `schoolsCollectionsRef` should probably be inside the dependency array, as well as `getSchools`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there anything wrong with using useEffect in this way?

Well there could be. *In general*, the advice is to list all variables (from component scope) that you use inside your `useEffect`, as dependencies. In your case `getSchools` is such a variable (even though it is a function - the function itself could be referencing some variables from component scope, and that could lead to stale closures). There is a [section](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) about this in the official docs, which you can check.

Since you can't move `getSchools` inside `useEffect` (because you use it elsewhere), I think you can go with this solution:

> As a last resort, you can add a function to effect dependencies but
> wrap its definition into the useCallback Hook

Also from the docs here is case when you can omit the function from dependencies:

> It is only safe to omit a function from the dependency list if nothing
> in it (or the functions called by it) references props, state, or
> values derived from them